# Removing references to paragraphes in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am using LaTeX and I keep getting the number of the paragraph where the citation was used next to every entry in the bibliography (Marked in red in the screenshot)

[image]

How can I remove these paragraph indicators?

**EDIT**: Here's my first attempt at a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=section,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 pdftex}
\usepackage{breakurl}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{algorithm}{tbp}{loa}
\providecommand{\algorithmname}{Algorithm}
\floatname{algorithm}{\protect\algorithmname}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.


\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{listings}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
\newtheorem{claimx}{Claim}
\let\doendproof\endproof
\renewcommand{\endproof}{~\hfill\qed\doendproof}

\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
 \PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
```

... I have my document here ... then I add the bibliography

```
\bibliographystyle{splncs03}
\bibliography{references}
```

Comment: How do you create your bibliography? How about providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the current setup?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I'm afraid that without any information about *how* the bibliography was created it's going to be impossible to offer a diagnosis, let alone a solution.

Comment: I have edited my question to include a hopefully good minimum working example.

Comment: In the options to `hyperref`, you have `backref=section`, delete this portion of code and the back references in the bibliography will disappear.

Comment: @FearUs Did the idea above solve your issue?

Comment: Yes it did, I am really sorry I didn't come back and let you know. I was on the move. Thanks.

Comment: @moewe I guess you can convert your comment above into an answer.

Comment: @Johannes_B Done ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `hyperref` set-up you have

```
backref=section
```

Which via the [`hyperref` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html)

> Adds ‘backlink’ text to the end of each item in the bibliography, as a
>   list of section numbers. This can only work properly if there is a
>   blank line after each `\bibitem`. Supported values are `section`, `slide`,
>   `page`, `none`, or `false`. If no value is given, section is taken as
>   default.

So in order to get rid of back-references, delete this line, or issue `backref=false` instead.